# ColDef is unable to render in Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to show data in ag grid on angular. However my [columnDefs] has some problems.

```html
<ag-grid-angular
   class = "ag-theme-alpine"
   [rowData]=rowData
   [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
   [columnDefs]=columnDefs>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

This is the error message, Type 'ColDef[]' is not assignable to type '(ColDef | ColGroupDef)[]'.ngtsc(2322)
database.component.ts(13, 3): Error occurs in the template of component DatabaseComponent.

```html
columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  { field: 'make' },
  { field: 'model' },
  { field: 'price' }
];
```

I have included my columnDefs in database.component.ts FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh, that's just a linting 'error' rather than anything specifically wrong.

JS (TS) doesn't do method overloading like, for example, C# can, so you end up with methods with parameters of various different types.

I try to avoid this to make my methods clearer, personally, at the loss of minor flexibility.

AG don't do this, however.

So their col defs are either a list of ColDef objects, OR a single ColGroupDef object (side note: I *really* hate it when there's overlap between objects and arrays) which helps to confuse matters.

The quick and dirty solution is to just tell it that it's `any` type and make it go away rather than be specific `columnDefs: any = [...]`.

Alternatively, you can define columnDefs properly as `columnDefs: ColDef[] | ColGroupDef = [...]`. That should shut it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have mixed up both module and library. I was importing ColDef from module (@ag-grid-community/core) which caused the issues. The errors gone after I import ColDef from library (ag-grid-community)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).